# ImportError using pyside

Tags: python, macos, qt, pyside

I need to use QT and pyside for a school project so hope to install pyside on my computer.

I struggled a little bit to install pyside and I eventually got pyside 1.2.4 installed using pip on both python 2.7 and 3.4.

However when I tried to use pyside-uic or import PySide.QtCore I got this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PySide/QtCore.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libpyside-python2.7.1.2.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PySide/QtCore.so
  Reason: image not found
```

I have been working on this for hours and tried to reinstall with macport.
I also tried to link QtCore.framework from other directory using:

```
ln -vis /usr/local/Cellar/qt/4.8.7_2/lib/QtCore.Framework /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PySide/QtCore.Framwork
```

nothing worked out and I'm still getting the same error. 
Please help and thank you guys so much.

Comment: I would suggest using homebrew instead, see http://pyside.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installing/macosx.html  -  make sure you end up using the correct version of Python too (you will have multiple copies of Python installed after this)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to set `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` ?

`export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Users/you/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PySide`

See here : https://github.com/PySide/PySide/issues/129

Comment: I think that is for installing pyside in python virtual environment, I tried it didn't work. Thanks anyway

Comment: Sorry I couldn't help more, I hope you fixed your issue.